# setting colors with pandas columns color

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I set up the data frame with color columns. When I am trying to use color value I couldn't use it.

`ax2.plot(xx.index, xx.close , linewidth=1, color = xx.color.values)`
This gives me

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: array(['green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red',
       'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red',
       'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red',
       'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green',
       'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green',
       'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'red', 'red', 'red',
       'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green',
       'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green',
       'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green',
       'green', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red',
       'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green',
       'green', 'green', 'green'], dtype=object)
```

If i use following code, it uses only the last row value. How can I fix it?

`ax2.plot(xx.index, xx.close , linewidth=1, color = xx["color"][-1])`

Comment: I believe `plot` only accept one color, not a list of colors.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I know. so I am trying to figure out how to get the value and use it as just one color?